# Restoring Rails 3's Bundle Install Path... It's now install in my root

Tags: ruby, bundler

I did something while trying to install the vestal_versions plug-in that ended up creating a vestal_versions directory in my app's root with the following:

```
 - Application
  - APP
  - DB
   - vestal_versions
    - ruby
     - 1.8
      - bin
      - cache
      - doc
      - gems
      - specifications
```

Which if deleted prevents the app from working... How do I update bundle to install all this stuff in the right place, which I believe is outside of the app?

Comment: bundler questions should provide some Gemfile content. What do you mean by 'update bundle to install (..) in the right place"? Do you mean 'update Gemfile'? what bundler commands did you issue? Please spend more time writing a good question so we best may help you.

Comment: To recap, when I run "bundle install" everything is now being installed in this new folder "vestal_versions" in my app's root folder (where app, db, config, etc.. all live). Before I messed up, any time I would run bundle install, files would not be installed in the app's root directory but some where outside of the app. How do I restore that behavior?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`bundle install <directory name>` makes the bundler install the gems in the respective directory.  Running `bundle install --system` will set the install directory back to the system directory rather than the custom one you provided.

Comment: Command is deprecated ( 2021 ), must use `bundle config set --local system 'true'`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found that I had a .bundler directory in my application's root folder that was causing this. After I removed the directory, the `bundle install` installed everything to the correct ruby directory again. Thanks to [this post by Caleb](http://blog.blenderbox.com/2010/09/25/bundler-installing-gems-into-the-rails-root-directory/).

Comment: That fixes a different problem, but it won't fix the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem a few times. From the root directory of your project check if you have a .bundle/config file. It should contain only:

```
--- {}
```

Delete anything else in the file and bundle install should return to installing outside of your project root.