# Rails & Bundler - gems installing inside rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, bundler

After a new install of osx rvm, bundler and rails 3 running bundle install somehow unpacks everything inside my application. I have done the following:

Installed rvm

```
$ bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

Added following to bash

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

Installed ruby via rvm

```
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm -default 1.9.2
```

Installed rails by rubygems

```
gem install rails
```

Installed bundler

```
gem install bundle
```

From within existing rails application installed my gems

```
bundle install
```

This results in the following directory structure **within** my application root directory:

```
mycoolblog/rails/ruby/1.9.1/bin | bundler | cache | doc | gems | specification
```

Clearly I've done something wrong with my installation but not sure how to fix it. **Please**, let me know if I need include any more details before voting to close this question.

Comment: like us. Start from the begininng

Comment: Did you actually vote to close my question yet leave a barely decipherable comment?

Comment: Maybe you're having the same problem from this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692188/restoring-rails-3s-bundle-install-path-its-now-install-in-my-root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone comes across this, the solution is:

```
rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/ .bundle/ Gemfile.lock
```

I have no idea how this came about so cannot elaborate other than the found fix.

Comment: If you still haven't found the cause of this , I foolishly ran `bundle install sass --local` and it created a bundle config file with saas as path. After this, all the bundle operations were taking off from sass folder until I found your answer. Thanks.