# How can I fix an accidental 'sudo bundle install dir_name'?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I accidentally ran `sudo bundle install smtp_mail` and now all my gems are in this directory called `smtp_mail` inside my Rails app.

I'm not sure about the default location of gems? And, my Rails app is complaining when it starts. Is there a way I can revert back?

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692188/restoring-rails-3s-bundle-install-path-its-now-install-in-my-root

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After a bit of Googling around i was able to find the answer
Just run:

`sudo bundle install --system` and you'll have your gems back at their appropriate system directories.

Answer (score 7):

The path is specified in a file located in

```
.bundle/config
```

If you delete the .bundle directory and then delete your smtp_mail directory you will be back at square one.  If you really want a local (to your app) installation of the gems, I recommend you run

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

pay attention on this...

from the bundle man page:

> By default, bundler installs gems to the same location as gem install.
>
> You should never use sudo bundle install. This is because several other steps in bundle install must be performed as the current user:
>
> - Updating your Gemfile.lock
> - Updating your vendor/cache, if necessary
> - Checking out private git repositories using your user's SSH keys
>
> Of these three, the first two could theoretically be performed by chowning the resulting files to $SUDO_USER. The third, however, can only be performed by actually invoking the git command as the current user. Therefore, git gems are downloaded and installed into ~/.bundle rather than $GEM_HOME or $BUNDLE_PATH.
>
> As a result, you should run bundle install as the current user, and bundler will ask for your password if it is needed to put the gems into their final location.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I was supposed to do, 'Sudo gem install smtp_mail' but, instead of gem I sonehow typed bundle, that was an error on my end. :)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me when I ran into a simular issue.

I rm -rf all files in .bundle and then removed and then I followed the commands in this document.

http://ruby-korea.github.io/bundler-site/issues.html.